# Form.Recordset Property (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, subforms

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-recordset-property-access

This link is exactly what I need, but after following it I still I can't get my subforms to refresh their data.  I have bound them to an ADO data source and when they are opened, the data displays correctly but when I change the underlying data for the subforms it doesn't display until I close and reopen the main form.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) 'Subform code fires when main form opens.
    Dim ADOcnn10 As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADOstr10 As String
    ADOstr10 = "Provider='Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0';Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=C:\data\Data.accdb;User ID=Admin;Data Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    Set ADOcnn10 = New ADODB.Connection
    ADOcnn10.Open ADOstr10

    Dim ADOrst10 As ADODB.Recordset
    Set ADOrst10 = New ADODB.Recordset
    ADOrst10.Open "SELECT * FROM tblTemp", ADOcnn10, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Set Me.Recordset = ADOrst10
    Forms(0).RecordSource = Forms(0).RecordSource
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. I don't see code specific to subforms, and `Forms(0).RecordSource = Forms(0).RecordSource` doesn't seem like a sensible line of code to me. Can you perhaps clarify exactly when the subforms stop displaying? Are you linking these subforms via the link master field - link child field, or are you manually linking via a WHERE clause in the recordset?

Comment: Ah, then I understand. Can you try `Me.MySubform.Recordsource = Me.MySubform.Recordsource` on the main form whenever the temporary table changes?

Comment: Sounds like you're having a problem with your connection. Try adding `Adorst10.CursorLocation = adUseClient` to make sure you're using a client-side cursor (I don't think the `Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0` provider supports server-side cursors, and you will need a valid cursor to refresh the form).

Answer (score 0):

I've opted for a workaround:
 1. ditching subforms and replacing them with independent forms
 2. .Requery still didn't work...
 3. so I now close and reopen the (what used to be subforms) in order to retrieve their latest recordset
The app now works fine with this approach.
If someone could recommend a course of study that would teach me to code correctly, great, otherwise...